# While using Mediatr for CQRS, if a property has a default value, does it add itself when not mentioning it

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5, mediatr

I use Mediatr for my CQRS and EF Core for DB access and entity configuration in my API.

I gave my `Spending` entity a configuration as such:

```
public class SpendingConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Spending>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Spending> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(p => p.Cost1)
                .HasDefaultValue(6.50)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Cost2)
                .HasDefaultValue(6.50)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Cost3)
                .HasDefaultValue(6.50)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.CurrentSpending)
                .HasDefaultValue(0.0)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.SpendingLimit)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.CreatedDateTime)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()");
        }
    }
```

Using Mediatr I need to create a `AddSpendingCommand` and a `AddSpendingCommandHandler`.

The `AddSpendingCommand` looks like this:

```
public class AddSpendingCommand : IRequest<Guid>
    {
        public string Cost1 { get; set; }
        public string Cost2 { get; set; }
        public string Cost3 { get; set; }
        public string CurrentSpending { get; set; }
        public string SpendingLimit { get; set; }
    }
```

And the `AddSpendingCommandHandler` like this:

```
public class AddSpendingCommandHandler
        : IRequestHandler<AddSpendingCommand, Guid>
    {
        // variables declaration

        public AddSpendingCommandHandler(IMapper mapper,
            ISpendingRepository repository)
        {
            // ctor stuff
        }

        public async Task<Guid> Handle(
            AddSpendingCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // validation stuff

            var convertedSpending = new Spending
            {
                Cost1 = double.Parse(request.Cost1),
                Cost2 = double.Parse(request.Cost2),
                Cost3 = double.Parse(request.Cost3),
                CurrentSpending = double.Parse(request.CurrentSpending),
                SpendingLimit = double.Parse(request.SpendingLimit)
            };

            // mapping stuff

            return spending.SpendingId;
        }
    }
```

My question here is, as you can see I've added **default values** to some properties of the `Spending` entity.

Do I need to add those properties with default values to the `AddSpendingCommand` method and manually map them to the `AddSpendingCommandHandler`'s `convertedSpending` object like when an object needs to map all of its properties to a DTO, or since in this case the user can only modify `SpendingLimit`, can I just add the properties I want to change, `CurrentSpending` and `SpendingLimit`, **not add the properties with default values** in the `AddSpendingCommand` and neither in the `convertedSpending` object and will those properties with default values will **be added anyway, on their own, using their default value** when I run `spending = mapper.Map<Spending>(convertedSpending);` to map them to their DTO even though I haven't mentioned them ?

EDIT

The `Spending` class:

```
public class Spending
    {
        public Guid SpendingId { get; set; }
        public double Cost1 { get; } // no setters, that's why can't add in Command
        public double Cost2 { get; }
        public double Cost3 { get; }
        public double CurrentSpending { get; set; }
        public double SpendingLimit { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    }
```

What I want to achieve:

`AddSpendingCommand`

```
public class AddSpendingCommand : IRequest<Guid>
    {
        public string CurrentSpending { get; set; }
        public string SpendingLimit { get; set; }
    }
```

`AddSpendingCommandHandler`

```
public class AddSpendingCommandHandler
        : IRequestHandler<AddSpendingCommand, Guid>
    {
        // variables declaration

        public AddSpendingCommandHandler(IMapper mapper,
            ISpendingRepository repository)
        {
            // ctor stuff
        }

        public async Task<Guid> Handle(
            AddSpendingCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // validation stuff

            var convertedSpending = new Spending
            {
                // Here I would not need to add the other properties,
                // their default values would be automatically added,
                // that's the question basically
                CurrentSpending = double.Parse(request.CurrentSpending),
                SpendingLimit = double.Parse(request.SpendingLimit)
            };

            // mapping stuff

            return spending.SpendingId;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *this case the user can only modify SpendingLimit* -- So only mark `SpendingLimit` as modified and EF will only update that field.

Comment: I see, should I create its own Update method in the repository or just having `SpendingLimit` in the `Command` will automatically make EF Core and Mediatr know I just want to change this property and the rest of the object will be included in the `Map` method without having to mention it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the `CurrentSpending` and `SpendingLimit` are strings in the `AddSpendingCommand` so that you can do some proper validation on those, but that the intent is that they should be invalid when they are not numeric.

Then there are two concerns: where to parse the strings to double, and where to map the command object to your domain object. There are no hard and fast rules of where to implement those concerns, but I will show you what I've done in the past.

For the first concern of parsing the strings to double, you can put them in the command, because that better reflects its intention:

```
public class AddSpendingCommand : IRequest<Guid>
{
    // ... other properties
    public string CurrentSpending { get; set; }
    public string SpendingLimit { get; set; }

    // simple implementation; you can put checks here
    internal double CurrentSpendingParsed => double.Parse(CurrentSpending);
    internal double SpendingLimitParsed => double.Parse(SpendingLimit);
}
```

Or if you have default values, for example declared in a `Constants` file:

```
public class AddSpendingCommand : IRequest<Guid>
{
    // ... other properties
    public string CurrentSpending { get; set; }
    public string SpendingLimit { get; set; }

    internal double CurrentSpendingParsed => double.TryParse(CurrentSpending, out double parsed) ? parsed : Constants.CurrentSpendingDefault;
    internal double SpendingLimitParsed => double.TryParse(SpendingLimit, out double parsed) ? parsed : Constants.SpendingLimitDefault;
}
```

For the second concern of mapping the command object to your domain object, you can put that in your mapper. Technically, you can also put the parsing logic in your mapper, but that makes it more complex than it needs to be. It makes the mapper object take on more responsibility (parsing) than it already has (mapping).

**Edit based on comment**

If you want to set default values of your `Spending` entity without having to mention them in the command, you can declare them in the `Spending` class itself:

```
public class Spending
{
    public double CurrentSpending { get; set; } = 1; // set default
    public double SpendingLimit { get; set; } = 10; // set default
}
```

Those properties will retain those values even if you don't map them from the command.

If the `Cost` properties have no setters, then their value cannot be set either from the command or even from Entity Framework. You need to compute them from within the `Spending` class:

```
public class Spending
{
    public double Cost1 { get; } => GetCost1(); // either a value or a method; I'm using a method in this case

    private double GetCost1()
    {
        // calculate cost1 here
    }

}
```

Comment: that's crazy, why not just define them as nullable decimal in the first place?

edit: I think you hit the nail on the head as to the motive of the question, it wasn't entirely clear to me when I read it.

Comment: I see. Is there an easier way to do it such as adding all the properties of the `Spending` entity to the `AddSpendingCommand` and when I do the `convertedSpending` mapping, I do something like `CurrentSpending = double.Parse(CurrentSpending.Default)` ? If not then I'll try with what you've said but the first concern wasn't converting the string to double but how to have the default value of the properties be added automatically without having to mention them inside of the `Command`. I'm asking that because I forgot to mention that `Cost1` etc have no getters.